# jquery expand only one textarea of multiple textareas with similar names

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple textareas with same name but different number at the end (e.g. desc1, desc2, desc3,...) I would like to expand only **ONE** of the textarea when I clicked and focused on that textarea. When that textarea loses focus, it should return to its original size. (Edited Note: After the webpage finish loading, there is only one textarea. User will have to click the add row button to show multiple textarea.)

```
<textarea name="desc1" placeholder="Description" class="form-control resizable itemDesc"></textarea>

<textarea name="desc2" placeholder="Description" class="form-control resizable itemDesc"></textarea>

<textarea name="desc3" placeholder="Description" class="form-control resizable itemDesc"></textarea>
```

This is the JQuery script I can come up so far:

```
// when itemDesc textarea is focused, expand
    $('textarea[name^="desc"]').focus(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "200px",
            width: "375px"
        }, 500);
    });

    // when itemDesc textarea lose focus, retract
    $('textarea[name^="desc"]').blur(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: "50px"
        }, 500);
    });
```

I know it is not working because it is selecting and expanding the first textarea only. How do I expand the textarea that I clicked on using JQuery?

Edited: I am so sorry for not providing a complete explanation to my case. Anyway this is the duplication code of textarea after clicking the add row button

```
//$("#add_row").trigger("click");
        $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
            // Dynamic Rows Code

            // Get max row id and set new id
            var newid = 0;
            $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
                //console.log($(this).data("id"));
                if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
                    newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                }
            });
            newid++;
            $("#table_row").val(newid);

            var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
                id: "addr" + newid,
                "data-id": newid,
            });

            //console.log(newid);

            // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
            $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
                var td;
                var cur_td = $(this);

                var children = cur_td.children();

                // add new td and element if it has a name
                if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
                    td = $("<td></td>", {
                        "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name"),
                    });
                    //tinymce.remove();
                    var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
                    /*if($(this).data("name") == "desc"){
                        c = $(cur_td).find('textarea').clone().val("");
                        c.attr("id", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                    }*/
                    if ($(this).data("name") == "quantity") {
                        c.val("1");
                    }
                    if ($(this).data("name") == "price") {
                        c.val("0");
                    }
                    if ($(this).data("name") == "position") {
                        c.val(newid);
                        td.addClass("hidden");
                    }
                    if ($(this).data("name") == "product") {
                        td.addClass("hidden");
                    }
                    c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                    c.attr("dataid", newid);
                    c.appendTo($(td));
                    td.appendTo($(tr));
                } else {
                    td = $("<td></td>", {
                        'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
                    }).appendTo($(tr));
                }

            });

            // add the new row
            $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

            $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                calc();
                for (i = 1; i <= $("#tab_logic tbody tr").length; i++) {
                    if ($('#addr0').length == 0) {
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i - 1) + ')').attr("name", 'addr' + i);
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i - 1) + ')').attr("id", 'addr' + i);
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i - 1) + ')').attr("data-id", i);
                        $.each($('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i - 1) + ') td'), function(index, value) {
                            $(this).children().attr("name", $(this).data("name") + i);
                            $(this).children().attr("dataid", i);
                        });
                        $('#table_row').val($("#tab_logic tbody tr").length);
                    } else {
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i) + ')').attr("name", 'addr' + i);
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i) + ')').attr("id", 'addr' + i);
                        $('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i) + ')').attr("data-id", i);
                        $.each($('#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(' + (i) + ') td'), function(index, value) {
                            $(this).children().attr("name", $(this).data("name") + i);
                            $(this).children().attr("dataid", i);
                        });
                        $('#table_row').val($("#tab_logic tbody tr").length - 1);
                    }
                }
            });

            //tinymce.init({menubar:!1,toolbar: false, statusbar: false,selector:"textarea",skin_url:$('meta[name="assets-path"]').attr("content")+"?path=js/skins/voyager",min_height:100,resize:"vertical"});
        });
```

Comment: your code is working fine. check here https://jsfiddle.net/1yeh60px/

Comment: In my site, it is not working. Perhaps I have omitted some of the codes which might have affected the script. I have edited the post to show more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple testing, I have found a solution for my case, which I believed would be a bit unique. Textarea named desc1 is by default in the webpage after loading, while other textareas would need to be created by clicking the add row button I have in the webpage. My button works by duplicating a textarea named desc0, which is hidden. Since the textarea (e.g. name="desc2" & name="desc3") is not loaded after the webpage finish loading, my speculation is JQuery script can't apply to newly created textarea. Hence, I used inline onfocus and onblur on html  tag of named desc0 and desc1. This is how the code would look like:

```
<textarea name="desc0" onfocus="$(this).animate({ height: '200px', width: '375px' }, 500);" onblur="$(this).animate({ height: '50px' }, 500);" placeholder="Description" class="form-control resizable itemDesc"></textarea>

<textarea name="desc1" onfocus="$(this).animate({ height: '200px', width: '375px' }, 500);" onblur="$(this).animate({ height: '50px' }, 500);" placeholder="Description" class="form-control resizable itemDesc"></textarea>
```

Textarea desc1 would work, since onfocus and onblur inline function is directly in its tag. By clicking the add row button, the entirety of textarea desc0 is being duplicated, including onfocus and onblur inline function.